# Why is GitHub replacing commit author name in my repositories?

Tags: git, github

I have created a new repository locally, made multiple commits and connected it to the newly created GitHub repository on my account. But for some reason GitHub changed author to "**ExampleOrgz**" instead of me. Even after connection to GitHub each next pushed commit is labeled as if was made by this account. This name is not present in any of my local or remote configurations. E.g my local git configs looks like this:

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=MyAccountName
user.email=dummy@email.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/MyAccountName/project.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And git log also points to my account's name:

```
commit 9e68892225f4d66172e62c43db131fb0543a50af (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: MyAccountName <dummy@email.com>
Date:   Tue May 2 04:10:06 2023 +0200
```

Although github account [ExampleOrgz](https://github.com/ExampleOrgz) seems to exist it is blank and has no connection to my own one. How can I fix this error and change my commits author on github to my own account?

P.S. I don't know if it might be an issue, but I've created fresh personal access token right before I connected my local repository to remote.

[image]

Comment: If account/organization "ExampleOrgz" has set "dummy@email.com" as their email address, commits with that email address will be associated with that account/organization. Which email address have you set in your own GitHub account? GitHub can only match accounts and email addresses on the configured email addresses. I doubt that's your real email address …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what concerns you is the mismatch between your real name and the one displayed on GitHub,  one possible solution would be changing the name in your passport! Just saying it's also a possible solution ;-)

On the serious side -

Please verify that the email set in the commits is really associated with your account as explained in the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/troubleshooting-commits/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user).

Comment: Yes indeed. I was into a process of configuring my new computer and placed a dummy email instead of my valid one. Which happened to by already taken by some long dead account. Silly me...

Thanks a lot for your help